# Wired & Wireless Connections simultaneously

Tags: wireless-networking, wired

Wired & Wireless Connections simultaneously

The question is how to configure LAN connections on PCs

please see image for details

[image]

Comment: So you want the ? bits filled in so you can get internet via the ethernet switch?

Comment: Please place the question itself on Superuser.

Answer (score 0):

For your IPs - anything thats not currently in use between 192.168.1.2 and 192.168.1.254 shoudl be useable on this network

It is worth looking at your router to see what addresses it hands out with DHCP over wireless and make sure you use a different address to stop conflicts

DNS, Default Gateway, Subnet mask will be the same on wired and wireless.  Subnet mask will be 255.255.255.0 and DFG/DNS will be 192.168.1.1