# If a computer is connected to internet by a wired as well as wireless connection, which would get a preference & why?

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, usb, internet-connection, tethering

I have connected my pc to internet by usb tethering and a hotspot point(in this case it is same as my mobile phone), which connection is my pc is going to use by default and which is better and why ?

I use both ubuntu and Windows 7, so what is the scenario in these 2 cases ?

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/727566/wired-wireless-connections-simultaneously

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/932312/using-wired-and-wireless-simultaneously

Answer (score 0):

The better option is the one that gives you a better connection because it gives you a better connection.

That is to say; only you can answer this question. Only you know what's "better" for you. One person prefers a slower but more stable connection over faster but more unstable. One person prefers the freedom of a hotspot connection, for another the privacy and security of a cable is absolutely critical. One person prefers the hotspot because the USB tethering in his phone is broken, and due to age of the phone no updates are coming. And so on.

Comment: I think he means which the computer "prefers" (aka uses). Not which connection a human should/would prefer.

Comment: That's the way I read "which is my pc using by default", but "what's better and why" is a separate question. If the OP confirms that I misunderstood the question, I'll of course be happy to remove my answer :-) I just answer to what I read, don't want to assume meanings because similar comparative questions where no definite answer can be given do pop up in these communities.

Comment: My pc is giving wired connection a prefrence most of the time, as it starts using the wired connection, soon after it is connected. I checked this through my internet speed meter as it is set to display only the speed of wired connection.

Comment: @Peregrino69, I think you are incorrect ,as considering the source is same there must be a one valid answer which is better, through my speed test performed on ookla, I am getting inconsistent results, sometimes wired is winning and sometimes wireless. So both are fine for me, but I just want to know which should be better from theoritical and hardware point of view

Comment: @RAHULJAISWAL There isn't. "Better" is always depending on the situation and the needs. My guess for why your PC prefers the cabled USB tether is that the connection simply opens faster. This is because opening a Wi-Fi connection requires association and authentication etc. before actual connection is availalble. That's why you can only do a speed comparison by connecting to one at a time, not by both connected.

Comment: Assuming there is no compromise and everything is upto the mark , then which is better.    I can do a speed test by connecting both at a time and its my observation that my pc is using only one to use internet, but for using wireless, I think I need to disconnect wired connection not vice versa.

Comment: @RAHULJAISWAL Speedtests over the internet never give you stable results. There's simply too much happening in between. If your internet connection is over 4G/5G etc. it will be even more inconsistent - it's a radio signal, and outside of a controlled lab or Faraday cage radio signals _always_ are affected by interference from other radio sources.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/129911/discussion-between-peregrino69-and-rahul-jaiswal).